# Keras C3DNN same result on prediction

Tags: neural-network, keras, classification

I'm trying to conduct variable-length multi-class sequence classification using a Conv3D Neural Network in Keras backed by Tensorflow.

I created a small example where I generate a distribution of input based on the label for the expected output. After training the network using an input generator, the result of the predictions is always the same value.

To reproduce:

```python
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Conv3D, Input, Flatten, Dense, Lambda, MaxPool3D, Dropout, Activation
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from random import randint
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
import keras.backend as K

#import os
#os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
HEIGHT = 40
WIDTH = 40
NDIMS = 1
NUM_CLASSES = 10

def get_data():
    nframes = randint(3,6)
    label = randint(0,NUM_CLASSES-1)
    x = np.array( ((label + 1) * 2)  * np.random.randn(nframes, HEIGHT, WIDTH, NDIMS))
    #print(np.std(x), label)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    y = keras.utils.to_categorical([label], num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
    return x,y

def input_generator():
    while True:
        x,y = get_data()
        yield (x, y)

def c3d():
    weight_decay = 0.005
    inputs = Input((None, HEIGHT, WIDTH, NDIMS))
    x = Conv3D(64,(3,3,3),strides=(1,1,1),padding='same',
            activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(inputs)
    x = MaxPool3D((2,2,1),strides=(2,2,1),padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv3D(128,(3,3,3),strides=(1,1,1),padding='same',
            activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda xa: K.sum(xa, axis=1))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(64,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(32,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(NUM_CLASSES,kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Activation('softmax')(x)

    lr = 0.005
    optimizer = Adam(lr=lr)
    model = Model(inputs, x)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = c3d()
    model.fit_generator(input_generator(), samples_per_epoch=10, nb_epoch=50, verbose=1)
    values = []
    argmaxes = []
    for i in range(100):
        x,_ = get_data()
        val = model.predict(x)
        values.append(val)
        argmaxes.append(np.argmax(val))
    print(argmaxes)
```

For the last print statement, the output looks like:

```python
[ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, ...
```

It chooses a random number within (0, NUM_CLASSES-1) and uses that for every prediction. There should be a pattern between the features and its label.

**Update: Breaking down the problem:**

I've reduced the problem to its more basic elements, but cannot yet get these results in the original problem (c3d). I've replaced the feature data with the label repeated, and I am able to get the network to somewhat learn that the value repeated n times is actually the classification. With either variable length or non-variable length, eyeballing the best last 10 average accuracies from the 3 activations at 500 samples per 5 epochs yields:

```python
Input, activation, learning rate, layer size, activation, accuracy, sequence
np.repeat: tanh 0.001 48 adagrad 0.46319999999999995 False
np.repeat: sigmoid 0.001 64 adam 0.4720000000000001 False
np.repeat: relu 0.001 64 adam 0.30519999999999997 False
```

To reproduce:

```python
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, Adagrad, RMSprop
from random import randint
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K

WIDTH = 40
NUM_CLASSES = 10
DIMENSIONS = 1
NO_SEQUENCE = False

def get_data():
    nframes = randint(3,6)
    label = randint(0,NUM_CLASSES-1)
    x = np.repeat(label, WIDTH * nframes).reshape(nframes, WIDTH).astype(np.float32)
    # x = np.array(((label + 1) * 2) * np.random.randn(nframes, WIDTH))
    if NO_SEQUENCE:
        x = x[0]
    # print(x, label)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    y = keras.utils.to_categorical([label], num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
    return x,y

def input_generator():
    while True:
        x,y = get_data()
        yield (x, y)

def cd(activation='relu', lr=0.0001, dense_size=16, optimizer=Adam()):
    if NO_SEQUENCE:
        inputs = Input((WIDTH,))
        x = Dense(dense_size, activation=activation)(inputs)
    else:
        inputs = Input((None, WIDTH))
        x = Dense(dense_size, activation=activation)(inputs)
        x = Lambda(lambda xa: K.sum(xa, axis=1))(x)
    x = Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(x)
    optimizer.lr = lr
    model = Model(inputs, x)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    activations = ['sigmoid', 'tanh', 'relu']
    learning_rates = [.01, .001, .0001, .00001]
    layer_sizes = [16, 32, 48, 64]
    optimizers = [('adagrad', Adagrad()), ('sgd', SGD()), ('rmsprop', RMSprop()), ('adam', Adam())]
    model = cd()
    print(model.summary())
    for a in activations:
        for lr in learning_rates:
            for ls in layer_sizes:
                for name, op in optimizers:
                    model = cd(a, lr, ls, op)
                    h = model.fit_generator(input_generator(), samples_per_epoch=500, nb_epoch=5, verbose=0)
                    print(a, lr, ls, name, np.average(h.history.get('acc')[-10:])) #average last 10 accuracies
```

**Questions:**

Why are my predictions coming out like this? How can I resolve this?
It seems like increasing the amount of training is yielding better results, but even when given an input of an array of the label, it still takes a significant amount of time to achieve an accuracy of 50%. How can I decrease this?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the training progress?

Comment: There's a lot of data. I'll try to post a gist of it tonight. It also takes a while to run. Was there anything specific you were looking for?

Comment: Just the evolution of the training (loss, metrics, etc.). The outputs of `fit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modification of your code that learns relatively steadily.
 I changed how the data is generated to be more deterministic, decreased l2, dropout, and learning rate, and increased the number of steps per epochs. The accuracy starts to steadily increase beyond what would be expected from random predictions. I think issue in your code is mostly connected to the fact `x = np.array( ((label + 1) * 2)  * np.random.randn(nframes, HEIGHT, WIDTH, NDIMS))` is still highly random even though there is some information about the label in it. Also the sharp decrease in dimensionality is suboptimal (you go from 102400 to 64 dimensions in 1 layer) which requires quite a few batches for network to properly filter the noise. Moreover with your original formulation of x it is unclear which dimension will contain useful information and coupling that with high dropout rate you were most definitely losing high amount of information in the tons of noise introduced by other random inputs

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Conv3D, Input, Flatten, Dense, Lambda, MaxPool3D, Dropout, Activation
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from random import randint
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
import keras.backend as K

#import os
#os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
HEIGHT = 40
WIDTH = 40
NDIMS = 1
NUM_CLASSES = 10

def get_data():
    nframes = randint(3,6)
    label = randint(0,NUM_CLASSES-1)
    x = label++np.random.randn(nframes, HEIGHT, WIDTH, NDIMS)
    #print(np.std(x), label)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    y = keras.utils.to_categorical([label], num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
    return x,y

def input_generator():
    while True:
        x,y = get_data()
        yield (x, y)

def c3d():
    weight_decay = 0.000
    inputs = Input((None, HEIGHT, WIDTH, NDIMS))
    x = Conv3D(64,(3,3,3),strides=(1,1,1),padding='same',
            activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(inputs)
    x = MaxPool3D((2,2,1),strides=(2,2,1),padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv3D(128,(3,3,3),strides=(1,1,1),padding='same',
            activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda xa: K.sum(xa, axis=1))(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(64,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.0)(x)
    x = Dense(32,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Dropout(0.0)(x)
    x = Dense(NUM_CLASSES,kernel_regularizer=l2(weight_decay))(x)
    x = Activation('softmax')(x)

    lr = 0.0001
    optimizer = Adam(lr=lr)
    model = Model(inputs, x)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = c3d()
    print(model.summary())
    model.fit_generator(input_generator(), samples_per_epoch=1000, workers=5, use_multiprocessing=True, nb_epoch=5, verbose=1)
    values = []
    argmaxes = []
    for i in range(100):
        x,_ = get_data()
        val = model.predict(x)
        values.append(val)
        argmaxes.append(np.argmax(val))
    print(argmaxes)
```

OUTPUT for the first 5 epochs where you can observe accuracy growing steadily and different labels being predicted:

```
1000/1000 [==============================] - 216s 216ms/step - loss: 1.6944 - acc: 0.3840
Epoch 2/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 222s 222ms/step - loss: 0.9882 - acc: 0.5920
Epoch 3/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 225s 225ms/step - loss: 0.7479 - acc: 0.7050
Epoch 4/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 221s 221ms/step - loss: 0.4670 - acc: 0.7950
Epoch 5/5
1000/1000 [==============================] - 214s 214ms/step - loss: 0.6742 - acc: 0.8040
[9, 5, 4, 8, 0, 7, 9, 2, 9, 1, 7, 7, 2, 5, 7, 2, 5, 2, 8, 5, 9, 9, 0, 3, 8, 1, 9, 7, 3, 9, 1, 0, 1, 4, 2, 0, 3, 5, 4, 4, 9, 7, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 0, 1, 6, 8, 4, 5, 9, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 7, 0, 0, 4, 7, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 3, 6, 2, 4, 7, 1, 2, 7, 3, 6, 1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 8, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9, 6, 6]
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you for this. I was able to reproduce this locally, and I really liked how you itemized specific points of my model that could have attributed to its failure, and also provided an example of how to get the accuracy up.